# How to display who logged in or logged out in last x seconds or minutes?

Tags: bash, shell-script, ubuntu

I am trying to achieve this on bash on Ubuntu 20.04. Any available command?

Comment: Is `who` mandatory? Comparing two lists of users logged in at the time will miss any user who logged in *and* logged out in between. `last` with `--since` seems a better start.

Comment: This isn't related to either bash or the bourne shell (which are not the same thing at all). The tools available will depend on your operating system, not your shell. Please [edit] your question and clarify what operating system you are using so we can know what tools would work.

Comment: Question edited

Comment: Use your system's logs. `sudo journalctl  --since="-5 minutes"`